# how to structure a site with 2 languages with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

can you help me to structure something like this, i have 3 roles, admin, operator and driver.

i imagine this like that:

```
 Controller -> folder
 Admin_Controller.rb
 Operator_Controller.rb
 Driver_Controller.rb

Model -> folder
 {

    //doesn't matted :)
 }

Views ->  folder
  Admin ->  folder
  Operator -> folder
  Driver ->  folder
```

is this the correct way to structure an application, and also i will need to add 2-3 languages.

but i doubt that the structure can be like this

```
Controller -> folder
 Order_Controller.rb
 Items_Controller.rb
```

and the admin, driver and operator is not declared explicitly

is have seen the structure for the gem "cancan" so there is the second method to structure, but i am confused about that, and yes this is in ruby on rails. thanks!!

Comment: try looking at `devise` gem. You have to create an `ACL` which seperates the roles of admin, operator & driver.

Comment: but i am now using clearance + cancan and i use the database to filter roles, is a bad solution?? i do something like this, if @user.role == "admin" then do let him manage, is this is an acl solution?? but now my question is about the site structure is this correct structure??